# Calculating % of conditional formatting

Tags: google

I've got a grid of cells filled with either a 'y' or an 'n'.

I'd like to work out the percentage of the 'y's.

So I need a formula that's something along the lines of:

Out of this selection, divide number of 'y's by 'y'+'n' x 100.

So I know what I need but not how to write it

Any help much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web application are you using? Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I have two options below.

### Option 1

This is shorter and assumes that you have only 'x' or 'y' in the grid and would

```
>> ... like to work out the percentage of the 'y's.
```

> =COUNTIF(range,"y")/COUNTA(range)

Range: the 'grid' that contains your "y" and "n" list.

Basically if you have 5 "y" and 5 "n" in the grid you will get 5/10=.5

Format the formula as % and the .5 will be 50%

### Option 2

Longer but will work if you have other items in the list than simply 'x' and 'y':

> =COUNTIF(range,"y")/(COUNTIF(range,"y")+COUNTIF(range,"x"))

### Note

I did not multiply the formulas by 100 as you would need to do in your head to calculate %.  Sheets properly displays values based on the number format chosen. Leaving this alone ensures you can always successfully perform calculations regardless the number format chosen.  You can test this yourself by entering 0.25 in a cell and then changing the number format.  Your cell values will be incorrect if you multiply by 100 because 50 percent doesn't equal 50, but rather it equals 50/100:

```
 Example:
 fraction + decimal + percentage + scientific e notation
  25/100  +   .25   +    25%     +       2.5e-1  
    
  = fraction = decimal = percentage = scientific e notation
  =  100/100 =    1    =     100%   =     1.00E+00
```